# About tween seek in Phaserjs3.60

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

Is it possible to implement a seek bar function with Tweens animations?
Is it also possible to rewind the Tweens animation with the seek function?
The version of PhaserJs is 3.60.

I am currently implementing the following, but the animation starts late and the object coordinates and rotation angle are wrong.

```
// Seek part
const scenesIndex = Object.keys(tweensArray); // The form of tweensArray is shown below
const totalTime = Math.floor((scenesIndex.length * 100) * (startSceneNumber / 100)); // startSceneNumber contains the value of what percentage to skip.
this.tweens.getTweens().forEach((tween) =>{
    tween.pause();
    tween.seek(totalTime, 16.6, true);
    tween.resume();
    tween.targets[0].x = (tween.getValue() == 0) ? -1000 : tween.getValue();
    tween.targets[0].y = (tween.getValue() == 0) ? -1000 : tween.getValue();
  });


// The animation is created as follows.
// There are n animations and n + 22 tweens.
const tweensArray = {
  1: [],
  3: [],
  5: [Tween2],
  8: [Tween2],
  10: [Tween2, Tween2],
  14: [Tween2, Tween2, Tween2],
  15: [Tween2, Tween2, Tween2, Tween2],
  16: [Tween2, Tween2, Tween2, Tween2],
  17: [Tween2, Tween2, Tween2, Tween2],
  21: [Tween2, Tween2, Tween2],
  n: [Tween2 * n],
};


/*
  Methods for creating animation.

  targetsObj  : targetsObj is a sprite object.
  　　　　　　　 this.add.sprite(-1000, -1000, 'ImgObj').setAlpha(0).setDepth(500);
  imgPosFinal : imgPosFinal contains x and y coordinates.
  angle       : angle is the angle of rotation.
  counter     : counter is a counter for delay.
*/
createTweensAnimation(targetsObj, imgPosFinal, angle, counter) {
    const tween = this.tweens.add({
      targets: TargetsObj,
      x: imgPosFinal.x,
      y: imgPosFinal.y,
      duration: 100,
      delay: counter * 100,
      persist: true,
      onStart: function() {
        TargetsObj.setAngle(angle);
        TargetsObj.setAlpha(1);
      },
      onPause: function() {
        console.log("onPause");
        TargetsObj.setAlpha(0);
      },
      onResume: function() {
        console.log("onResume");
        TargetsObj.setAlpha(0);
      }
    })
    return tween
}
```

Comment: you are not tweening the rotation, or am I missing something in this code? you are just setting the angle on start and on pause.

Comment: Is your question solved? If so and my answer help please consider accepting it with the green checkmark unter the voting arrows.

Comment: When I set the initial values of the sprites to -1000 for x and y and 0 for Alpha, and the animation starts, the initial values are updated by updating x and y, the rotation angle is updated by onStart, and Alpha is displayed at 1, but when I seek, the sprites are displayed in the upper left corner of the screen (0, 0). However, when I seek, the sprites are displayed in the upper left corner of the screen (0, 0) or moved from (0, 0).
If I seek continuously, it behaves more strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Without seening more code I must guess, that said, if I'm not missing something the time mismatch, could have to do with the `totalTime` calculation, since one would assume, that entries (of the `tweensArray`  Array) without tweens(empty arrays), like entries `1` and `3` shouldn't be counted to create the `totalTime`, but these are not excluded. In that case changing the line to:

```js
const scenesIndex = Object.values(tweensArray).filter(item => item.length> 0);
```

might help fix this issue.

> ***Disclaimer:** Without more inside into the code or idea, I'm just "guessing".*

> **btw:** the second parameter, of the `seek` function, can also be the fault of missing precision, you could make it smaller to increase precision. *([checkout the documentation for details](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tweens.Tween.html#seek__anchorhttps://))*

> **btw2.:** did you include the `delay` in the totalTime calculation? *Since (delay + duration) = Total length for the Tween, atleast for the `seek` function calculations.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Increasing the delta value improved the speed But what is the appropriate delta value?

Comment: The delay is set by the number of animations * 100.

If there are 5 animations and duration = 100, would ((5 * 100) + 1500) = 2000 be the total length?

Comment: In your code you are setting the `delay` of the tween as `delay: counter * 100` so the delay doesn't seem to be always the same value, you would have to consider this also. I hope this clears up the situation

Comment: If the amount of animation is large and multiple objects are moved in one animation, is it inevitable that seek() will take a long time when accuracy is required?

Comment: I can't really say since I didn't read the implementation of phaser's `seek` function ([link to github](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.55.2/src/tweens/tween/Tween.js#L878)), and to be frank, I don't 100% understand your usecase. The only thing I can say from reading the docs and my own small tests, 1) you have to include tween-delay in the seek value, 2) depending on the length of the tween a higher or lower `delta` is better to find the position _"faster"_, (although in my test the speed was not really an issue).